# AS3 with alivePDF Embedding Fonts - Unable to transcode .afm

Tags: actionscript-3, fonts, alivepdf

I've tried adding the `/` at the front like many other forums and blogs suggested and that didnt work.

I'm hoping I missed something, and you guys can help me catch it. I'm using the `AlivePDF` library its working fine so far until now, I am trying to embed the `swiss-721-bold-outline`, here is my code:

```
[Embed( source="/../swissFonts/swz721bo.TTF", mimeType="application/octet-stream" )]
        var swissBold:Class;

[Embed( source="/../swissFonts/swiz721bo.afm", mimeType="application/octet-stream" )]
        var BoldAfm:Class;

var regularSwiss:EmbeddedFont = new EmbeddedFont(new swissBold() as ByteArray, new BoldAfm() as ByteArray, CodePage.CP1252);
```

Simple, but I keep getting these errors:

```
Unable to resolve '/../swissFonts/swiz721bo.afm' for transcoding
Unable to transcode /../swissFonts/swiz721bo.afm.
```

Notice that the `.TTF` file has no errors, just the `.afm` ...

Answer (score 0):

Is the afm file using the cp1252 map? This tool is mentioned for encoding afm files from ttf http://fpdf.fruit-lab.de/index.php

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify fontName.

```
[Embed(source="/../swissFonts/swz721bo.TTF",fontName="swz721bo",mimeType="application/octet-stream")]
var swissBold:Class;
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same error:

> `flex air Assets.as(34): Error: exception during transcoding:`
>   `Error: unable to build font 'FontName'`

To solve it I added this line:

```
-managers flash.fonts.AFEFontManager
```

to <kbd>Project Properties</kbd> > <kbd>Compiler Options</kbd> > **<kbd>Advanced Compiler Options</kbd>**